# Inconsistent display of zero value

Tags: google-sheets

I have several cells which are formatted to hold "Accounting" values.  Their values are all defined using some variant of this formula:

```
=sum(SomeColumn1:SomeColumn1000)+sum(OtherColumn1:OtherColumn1000)
```

When the value is 0, most of the cells display as `$  -`  .  However, a few of them display as `$  0.00`.

What is the cause for this inconsistency and what can I do to enforce the first format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
=round(sum(SomeColumn1:SomeColumn1000))+round(sum(OtherColumn1:OtherColumn1000))
```

the 0.00's are likely non-zero values due to [floating point errors](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/17231111?hl=en) further upstream in your sheet than that particular formula you're asking about.

Comment: That was it.  Perfect!